# ご堪能 usage and meaning

Tags: meaning, usage, song-lyrics

残り僅かな命をご堪能

According to a dictionary, *tannou* can be used as an adjective or a verb (to enjoy, be satisfied, to be skilled, ect.) But I don't understand it here.

> ►残り僅かな命をご堪能
>   手元に残す切り札のカード
>   I know ここで引くなどご法度
>   ギリギリで生きるのがスタンダード

This is the full line, which might help you with the context. It’s from a song I was translating. I don’t need help with the lines below it, and I just didn’t want to get deleted if someone thought I was asking for a bulk translation (because I'm not).

Comment: Please specify the source of the lines, especially when you're dealing with song lyrics, which are almost always very tricky. How can we know the context only from those lines?

Comment: Sorry. I would have, but this website doesn't like requests for translations from songs. I thought if I mentioned it by name (something I did in my very first post) it would get deleted again.

Comment: Questions about song lyrics [are welcome](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/song-lyrics) here (as long as your question is specific and you show your own research effort). Questions without enough context are always frowned upon :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

堪能 here is clearly used as a suru-verb because it has a direct object (残り少ない命). Its meaning here is "to enjoy to one's heart's content." する is omitted because it's from lyrics, and it's intended to rhyme with ご法度 two lines after it.

Judging from the [whole lyrics](https://lyricsjpop.blogspot.jp/2016/12/sky-hi-double-down.html), this is a song about [double down of blackjack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackjack#Player_decisions), which is a symbol of a make-or-break, sink-or-swim situation. So this 残り少ない命を堪能する figuratively refers to the excitement of a person placed in such a situation.

Comment: So, is he personally saying 'I am excited, and enjoying this (game) to my heart's content?'

Comment: @PinkuNoUsagi No, the song is clearly written from the "dealer's" (or third person's) point of view, and he's not the one who may have to die. "(you must) enjoy the little remaining life of yours."

Answer (score 2):

The 「を」 particle is used to indicate the object of the verb.

Noun + を + Verb = Verb + the Noun

残り僅かな命 + を + (ご)堪能 = Enjoy + the little remaining life

There isn't enough context to give a precise translation that matches the intent, but the gist here is to "Enjoy the little bit of life one still has left." (Sounds like something we'd read about when speaking of patients with terminal illnesses.)

Comment: Not sure why this answer got downvoted, but this was in response to the original question which was worded quite differently from the current version after being edited by OP to provide more context.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't make any sense.
And 堪能 itsself means' to be fully satisfied with' something 
especially like luxury foods, trips, or performances of eminent artists.
So technically you can say 残りわずかな命を堪能する
but this sounds really strange. I would substitute 享受する kyouju-suru
(accept and enjoy) for 堪能する in this context.
残り僅かな命を享受する is more natural expression.

I'd like to add one thing concerning 堪能.
If you see 堪能 in other contexts like 彼は英語に堪能である。
Here 堪能 serve as a na-adjective meaning 'He is very good at English.'